# SQL - sorting DATE_FORMAT by weekdays from Monday to Sunday

Tags: mysql

I have a query that gets distinct weekdays (data_format on the dates), and I would like to have it sorted from Monday till Sunday. Till now is weekdays alphabetically.

Query:

```
SELECT distinct DATE_FORMAT(cleaningdate, '%W') as contract_weekday 
FROM cleaning 
ORDER BY contract_weekday
```

Help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a numeric representation of the day to sort and you get it with [`weekday()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday):

```
order by weekday(cleaningdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(cleaningdate, '%W') as contract_weekday 
FROM cleaning 
GROUP BY cleaningdate
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(cleaningdate, '%w')
```

Here i added `DATE_FORMAT(cleaningdate, '%w')`

> %W Weekday name (Sunday..Saturday)
>
> %w Day of the week

Comment: Good answers should include a explainment how or why it works not only a try this, which you seams to do alot when i look into the answer history.. You risk your answer will be marked to be deleted because it's containing to less content or low quality.

Comment: This will sort from Sunday to Monday, not Monday to Sunday.

Comment: `ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(cleaningdate, '%w')` will sort Monday to Sunday